# Datagridview.datasource=null

Tags: c#

I want to filter the data in a datagridview.
I want to do this with the following code:

```
DataView view = new DataView();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = Tbl_events.DataSource as DataTable;
view = dt.DefaultView; 
view.RowFilter = "Type='1301'";
Tbl_events.DataSource = view;
```

This gives me an empty datagridview.
When debug the code i see that on this row:

```
dt = Tbl_events.DataSource as DataTable;
Tbl_events.DataSource = null;
```

but there is data in the datagridview Tbl_events.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is Tbl_Events here..

Comment: Can you show the code where you initially set the `DataSource` property of `Tbl_events`?

Comment: Tl_events is a datagridview

Comment: Tbl_events.Rows.Add(DataContainer.foutinformatie[0, lusteller], DataContainer.foutinformatie[1, lusteller], DataContainer.foutinformatie[2, lusteller], DataContainer.foutinformatie[3, lusteller], DataContainer.foutinformatie[4, lusteller]);

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code:

You are using add a rows. first convert to datatable then using filtering and add datatable to datagridview

```
     foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in dataGridView1.Columns)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(c.HeaderText.ToString()));
            }


        for (int row = 0; row < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; row++)
        {
            // create a new dt row to match up with the rows in the DGV
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            int column = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in dataGridView1.Columns)
            {
                //Sure you can see what this is doing.
                dr[c.HeaderText.ToString()] = dataGridView1.Rows[row].
                   Cells[column].Value;
                column++;
            }

            //now i add the row to the data table.
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }


        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
 dt = dt.Select("Type='1301'").CopyToDataTable();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

EDIT

```
 DataView view = new DataView();
            view = dt.DefaultView;
            view.RowFilter = "Type='1301'"
 dataGridView1.DataSource = view;
```

Comment: when I try this i get an error with object reference not set to an in instance of an object.

Comment: @user2261091 which place your using above coding because its produce reslut for me.

Comment: what do you mean? How a I place data in the table?

Comment: This i do with this code Tbl_events.Rows.Add(DataContainer.foutinformatie[0, lusteller], DataContainer.foutinformatie[1, lusteller], DataContainer.foutinformatie[2, lusteller], DataContainer.foutinformatie[3, lusteller], DataContainer.foutinformatie[4, lusteller]);

Comment: @user2261091 DataContainer,lusteller it means what?

Comment: thats a variable in a class.

I will add multiple rows to my datagridview.  Datacontainer.Foutinformatie is an array with al the data for my datagridview.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

When I try your code I've got an datagrid with empty lines.

Comment: I have the number of empty lines then I have lines with type of 1301

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. When i want to add .copytodatatable my visual studio don't recognize these functions. Must i add a special dll for it?

Comment: I work with the .net framework 3.5

The error is :System.array does not contain a definiton for copytodatatable and no extension method copytodatatable  accepting a first argument of type system.array could be found are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: That gives the same problem.

Comment: This gives me the data after my rows of my table. there were add new rows

Comment: I have also a second problem. Now when i want to re-add the data from my sql server in my table i have en error: rows cannot be programmatically added to the datagridview's rows collection when the control is data-Bound. I think this error is excist because the code for the filter. Because before I had no error on this.

Answer (score 0):

view.RowFilter = "Type='1301'";

view.RowStateFilter = DataViewRowState.CurrentRows;

// The following calls a different method to display the

// data view contents.

Tbl_events.DataSource = DataView1;

Tbl_events.DataBind();

Comment: Tbl_events don't recognize Databind(); Must i add a dll for it?